# Problem with performance when loading PostGIS layer using pyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I'm having a question on loading a PostGIS layer into the project from my QGIS plugin.
The code is like this:

```
uri1 = qgis.core.QgsDataSourceURI() 
uri1.setConnection(str(host), str(port), str(database), str(user), str(password) )
uri1.setDataSource(str(schema), "layer", "geom")
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri1.uri(),"layer", "postgres")
```

It actually works fine but the performance is causing me lots of troubles. It takes up to 10 minutes, since there are about a 100,000,000 entries in the table.

When I load the layer manually using the PostGIS button on QGIS, there is a checkbox in the settings which says: "Geschätzte Tabellenmetadaten nutzen". In english this would be: "Use estimated table metadata". 
When checked, the layer loads in realtime.

My question is: Is there a way to load a PostGIS layer into QGIS using the estimated table metadata, and thus increase performance significantly?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
uri1.setUseEstimatedMetadata(True)
```

before setting the connection ?